# Ubuntu install on Asus UEFI network not working

Tags: networking, system-installation, uefi, asus

I did a complete wipe of my windows 8 and replaced it with Ubuntu (ASUS V500CA-BB31T). When I boot into Ubuntu none of the networking works, not even the Ethernet cable is recognized.

When installing, I followed [this guide](http://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?33640-GUIDE-Dual-boot-for-pre-installed-Windows-8-and-Ubuntu-13.04-on-Asus-G75VW) mostly.

This was the main step I followed to get Ubuntu installed:

1. If you just press install option, installation will hang. You need to edit the installation command:

   - Press 'e' to enter on edit mode.
   - Replace where it says 'quiet splash' with 'nomodeset'
   - Press Ctrl-X to boot and install.

I haven't used the new installation much and would be fine with reinstalling.

Comment: Any luck with the networking? I am also interested in Ubuntu on the ASUS V500CA-BB31T.

Comment: Please help us help you by providing more information. If you choose "Try Ubuntu" from the live install disk does the networking behave differently? How did you perform a "complete wipe"?